# Test TCP connection to a socket.io node app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to test a TCP connection to a socket.io. It appears to connect but when I pass a message it closes.

Here is my telnet command:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ me$ telnet 34.111.161.111 8080
Trying 34.111.161.111...
Connected to ec2-54-235-555-134.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
alert_me  <-- my input
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Here is my server.

```
     if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
    return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
  };
}

function log_me(msg){
  var ts = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (3600000*4));
  var tss = ts.toString();
  tss = tss.substring(0, tss.indexOf(' GMT'));
  console.log(tss + ": " + msg);
}


var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('join_channel', function(channel){
    log_me("join_channel: " + channel);
    socket.channel = channel;
    socket.join(channel);
  });
  // unused
  // this comment does nothing
  socket.on('alert_me', function(channel, data){
    log_me("alert_me: " + channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('alert', data);
  });
  // k
  socket.on('call_me', function(channel, data){
    log_me("call_me: " + channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('call', data);
  });
  // k

  // anything that disconnects
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    log_me("disconnect: " + socket.channel);
    if(socket.channel){
      if(socket.channel.startsWith("a_")){
        var c = socket.channel.replace("a_", "");
        var data = {'ambulance_id' : c, 'status' : 'DISCONNECTED'}
        io.sockets.in(c).emit('status_update', JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    }
    socket.leave(socket.channel);
  });
});

  server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: You need to connect with a webbrowser `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>`  take a look here https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: In Node.js in order to communicate with `telnet`, you need to run a `net.Server`

Answer (score 3):

You can't connect to a socket.io server with a telnet server.  They don't speak the same connection sequence or protocol.

A socket.io connection consists of the following:

- socket.io connection scheme that starts with polling, then transitions to webSocket
- socket.io message data format
- running over a webSocket which has it's connection scheme which starts with an http request that is then "upgraded" to the webSocket protocol
- running over a webSocket which has it's own data frame and security scheme
- running over a TCP socket as the transport

To connect to a socket.io server, you need ALL of those.  So, you can only communicate with a socket.io server using a full-blown socket.io client.  Anything less will be missing some part of the connection scheme or data format which will be an immediate violation of something the server is expecting and the connection will be immediately closed.

So, you need both ends of your connection to be speaking the same protocol and connection scheme.  Some choices:

1. socket.io client <==> socket.io server
2. webSocket client <==> webSocket server
3. http client <==> http server
4. Custom TCP client <==> custom TCP server (using your own invented protocol)

If the socket.io server is what the server is and you're trying to connect to it, then you need a socket.io client in order to establish a connection and exchange messages.